# PlayonLinux with AMDGPU-PRO

Tags: playonlinux

I'm using Playonlinux with Origin and Steam. Fifa 12 and Trackmania2 Stadium works with Opensource amdgpu drivers, but are a little bit slow. With opensource drivers glxgears shows 60fps, and with gpu-pro shows near 800

When I try to play games, Origin and Steam works, but when I launch the games I have OpenGL and hardware errors, and is impossible to start them.

The question is, is possible to get work wine with the amd drivers???

Thank you!!

--EDIT--

I'm on Lubuntu 16 64Bit, but on playonlinux I configured 32 bit wine, I saw that is better.

-- EDIT2 --

Here are the messages (all with wine-1.9.17):

```
STEAM / TM2:

La tarjeta no soporta los requisitos mínimos (DX9 = ShaderModel2).
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast

ORIGIN / FIFA 12

Error 0001.

err:module:import_dll Library Qt5Svg.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\Origin\\imageformats\\qsvg.dll") not found
err:ole:CoInitializeEx Attempt to change threading model of this apartment from apartment threaded to multi-threaded
err:winediag:X11DRV_WineGL_InitOpenglInfo Direct rendering is disabled, most likely your 32-bit OpenGL drivers haven't been installed correctly (using GL renderer "Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.8, 1fixme:d3d:wined3d_guess_card No card selector available for card vendor 0000 (using GL_RENDERER "Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.8, 128 bits)").
err:ole:CoInitializeEx Attempt to change threading model of this apartment from apartment threaded to multi-threaded:
```

Comment: Can you provide the errors? What makes you think it is drivers? Fifa 12 is old, it used to work but I doubt it has any support now, Ubuntu has changed a lot https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=24481 and Trackmania 2 was never working that well https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=29583

Comment: Added errors on first post. Trackmania2 runs very very well, very smooth, perfect. Is a driver problem because with amdgpu opensource runs.

Comment: OK it looks like it is complaing about you using a 32 WINE on a 64bit distro `Direct rendering is disabled, most likely your 32-bit OpenGL drivers haven't been installed correctly` First is amdgpu installed correctly? check with `dpkg -l amdgpu-pro` to make sure. IDK if amdgpu even has 32bit support and you should use 64bit WINE for a 64bit OS.

Comment: dpkg says all ok, is installed correctly. Then, how I can use a 64 bit wine on Playonlinux?? When I click on non listed program to install, 64 bit wine not appears....

Comment: Run these commands `export WINEPREFIX=prefix64` then `export WINEARCH=win64` and `winecfg` that should put it in 64bit mode.

Comment: Well, I reinstalled all with a wineprefix 64 bit and still saying the same error....

Comment: Sorry, we a really pushing the limits of my knowledge of WINE now, I can't find any documentation or anything on this, amdgpu is too new.

Answer (score 0):

You will need 32 bit Wine and 32 bit Mesa

`sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`

`sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`

This should bring in all the 32 bit versions of apps you already have installed. Answer Y to install them all if prompted.

Comment: Not worked. Still the same errors. I think this problem is related to amdgpu-pro and the 64 bit-only package. Seems not have the 32 bit drivers that playonlinux need....but...is strange, I created a wineprefix 64 bit, and origin is running on 64 bit....

Comment: I don't use PoL. Are you able to test from the command line that your graphics drivers are installed correctly?From a terminal enter `glxinfo | grep -i opengl`. You should get output similar to `Gallium 0.4 on AMD` rather than gallium on llvmpipe (I believe this is the software renderer so is not using the AMD card. Once you have your graphics drivers sorted you will also need to create a 32bit prefix in POL rather than using a 64bit prefix. As an added note I recently had to reinstall my system and am able to run 32 & 64 bit wine apps using the AMDGPU-Pro driver without having to install Mesa